# Parallel ajax calls in different components of parent component

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am making a react application. I have two components in my application. Header and Files List. In header I have a drop down button which has three options : Media Files, Jobs and New Media Files. All three options are for three different Files list. When I choose any one of them, the complete Media files should change.

Hear is that I tried:

1). Store state of drop down button in reducer.
2). In "Files" component, map all the three component (Media Files, Jobs and New Media Files) to this drop down state. Render accordingly.

Problem is ajax call. Each of the three components (Media Files, Jobs and New Media Files) fetch the files from an api. So I have made an ajax call in each one of them. I make this ajax call in componentsWillMount Method of these components.

Things are not working as expected. One of the component's items always remains unfetched. I think due to parallel ajax call this is happening.

What is the best way to do this?

HEar is my code

index.js  (hear I check the state of dropdown button and render component accordingly)

```
render(){

var MediaFilesView;
if(this.props.search_option_changed_reducer.index == 1){
    MediaFilesView = <ReviewTable
        //items={this.props.list}
        selectedRows={this.props.selectedRows}
        authToken={this.props.auth_token}
        onRowSelection={this.onRowSelection}
        setCurrentItem={this.setCurrentItem}/>
}

if(this.props.search_option_changed_reducer.index == 2){
    MediaFilesView = <JobsTable
        //items={this.props.list}
        selectedRows={this.props.selectedRows}
        authToken={this.props.auth_token}
        onRowSelection={this.onRowSelection}
        setCurrentItem={this.setCurrentItem}/>
}

if(this.props.search_option_changed_reducer.index == 3){
    MediaFilesView = <MediaFilesPage
        //items={this.props.list}
        selectedRows={this.props.selectedRows}
        authToken={this.props.auth_token}
        onRowSelection={this.onRowSelection}
        setCurrentItem={this.setCurrentItem}/>
}



return (
    <div className={c.container}>
        <ReviewSearch
            assignIsOpen={this.state.assignIsOpen}
            toggleAssign={this.toggleAssign}
            selectedRows={this.props.selectedRows}
            onSubmitProcess={this.onSubmitProcess}
            toGroups={this.toGroups}
        />
        {MediaFilesView}
        <AddFileButton
            openFileUpload={this.openFileUpload.bind(this)}
            fileUploadIsOpen={this.state.fileUploadIsOpen}
        />
    </div>
)
```

}

ReviewTable.js

ReviewTable.js

```
 componentWillMount = ()=> {
        var that = this;
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://www.br.example.com//api/v1/workgroups/",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
        },
        success: function( response, textStatus, jQxhr ){
            var settings_second = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url":  response.results[0].url + "tagging_jobs/",
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
                },
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    //that.setState({MediaFiles: data})
                    that.props.MediaFilesChangeAction(data, response.results[0].url + "tagging_jobs/")
                    //console.log(that.state.MediaFiles)
                },
            }
            $.ajax(settings_second).done((response) => {
                //alert("yo");

            });
        },
    }


    $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
        //alert("yo");
        console.log('check');
    });


}



render(){
        return (
            <Table
                height='600px'
                ref={(el)=> this.table_el = el }
                fixedHeader={true}
                multiSelectable={true}
                onRowSelection={this.props.onRowSelection}>
                <TableHeader
                    className='table-header'
                    style={{fontFamily: 'montserratregular'}}
                    adjustForCheckbox={true}>
                    <TableRow className='table-header-row' style={{height:'10'}}>
                        <TableHeaderColumn  className='th-filename'> Filename </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn> Channel </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn> File Type </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn> Uploaded </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn> TX Date </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn> Process </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn> Assigned </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn> Status </TableHeaderColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody
                    showRowHover={true}
                    deselectOnClickaway={false}>
                    {
                        this.props.media_file_store.MediaFiles.map((item,i)=> (
                            <TableRow
                                key={i}
                                className={`table-item-${i}`}
                                selected={this.props.selectedRows.includes(i)}>
                                <TableRowColumn className='td-filename' onMouseUp={this.showVideo(item.video.file, item.video.id, item.video.title, item.video.duration, item.video.height, item.video.width, item.video.frame_rate)}>
                                    <div className='item-file-details'>
                                        <div className='file-image' style={{backgroundImage: `url('${item.video.poster.list_thumbnail}')`}}/>
                                        <div className='details'>
                                            <p className='detail-name'> {item.video.title} </p>
                                            <p className='detail-type'>{this.secondsToHms(item.video.duration)}  </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>
                                    <p className="file-channel">kampe</p>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>
                                    <p className="file-duration">Movie </p>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>
                                    <p className="file-upload-date">{item.video.created_on}</p>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>
                                    <p className="file-tx-date">20-02-17</p>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn className='process-column'>  </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>
                                    <p className="file-assignee">Apurv</p>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn
                                    className={this.getStatusClassName(item.job_status)}>
                                    {this.jobStatus(item.job_status)}
                                </TableRowColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))
                    }
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        )
    }
```

Only one ajax gets executed. In my network table ajax of MediaFilesPage gets executed, no view gets rendered in that too.

Comment: I think you should narrow down the problem. Have you verified that your 3 AJAX requests are being made and a response is being returned? (Can see in your browser's developer tools, e.g "network" tab in Chrome.) Are the callback handler functions being called for the AJAX requests? You should be able to track this down to a solution or simpler question with some troubleshooting, setting breakpoints, console logs, etc.

Comment: @ApurvG, your `ReviewTable.js` seem to be missing, could you show that too? And I would abstract your `MediaFilesView` in a method.

Comment: @ErikHermansen No only one ajax gets called while rendering index.js.

Comment: @flash added in question. Have a look

Comment: @ApurvG, a quick thing I noticed in your headers out of curiosity is the word `Token`, do you want to do `Bearer` instead? Will look more closely at the code.

Comment: @flash the problem was I was setting the state in other component wrongly. I was using this.state = something. When I changed it to this .setState then things worked fine.